# Enable soap for php in docker container

Tags: php, docker, soap

I have been unable to get soap to work with my php Docker setup.

I am using Docker CE for Windows Version 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513). PHP version 7.2.3

I've tried running from inside the container `apt-get install php-soap` which results in 
*Reading package lists... Done*

*Building dependency tree*

*Reading state information... Done*
*
*Package php-soap is a virtual package provided by:*
*  php7.0-soap 7.0.27-0+deb9u1 [Not candidate version]*

E: Package 'php-soap' has no installation candidate

Running `docker-php-ext-install soap`
 results in the error configure: error: libxml2 not found. Please check your libxml2 installation.

However when looking at php info I see the following:
*libxml2 Version => 2.9.4*

Comment: whenever you're configuring and you get that sort of error, you need the "-dev" package

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You will need to install libxml2-dev as part of your dockerfile, the image is kept to a minimum and doesn't include all of the bits needed by every module.  Although the image may have the main package, the -dev package includes the components needed to compile other modules which rely on it...

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
```

(From https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/315)

Just to make it clear - the command

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
```

will then run successfully to install the soap library.

Comment: Thanks. Will that only work as part of the docker build though? I've already run that in the container and the phpinfo suggests it is already installed.

Comment: You should be able to log into the container and run the apt-get install.  The install adds the -dev package which is different to the one used by the PHP exe itself.

Comment: Never tried running `docker-php-ext-install soap` in the container, so would be interested if that runs.

Comment: For alpine-based containers the first command should be: `apk update && apk add libxml2-dev`

Answer (score 28):

For me, working with PHP 7.3.2, the other solutions didn't work.

Both "php-soap" and "php7.3-soap" got "phpXXX-soap has no installation candidate" error.

Alone "docker-php-ext-install soap" wanted the "libxml2-dev" so i just installed the necessities:

```
FROM php:7.3
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
     libxml2-dev \
  && apt-get clean -y \
  && docker-php-ext-install soap
```

... and it worked nicely.

Comment: I get the error `ERROR: Module soap does not exist!` when trying this with `FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch`

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer was done, but for me, I needed also to enable (**docker-php-ext-enable soap**) the soap module, so for If someone could be useful:

```
FROM php:7.4.24-apache

# your configurations ...

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap && docker-php-ext-enable soap

# other configurations ...
```

Answer (score -1):

This is outside the scope of this repo.

You should get it via this approach:

```
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
     libxml2-dev \
     php-soap \
  && apt-get clean -y \
  && docker-php-ext-install soap
```

Comment: in this case `php-soap` will return an error because there is no such package in php7.2